# jOOQ code generation fails on triggers - how to skip them?

Tags: triggers, jooq, jooq-codegen-maven

In my application I use Flyway to migrate the database. I have a SQL file containing the database structure which includes some `CREATE TRIGGER` statements. jOOQ code generation fails because it uses H2 which does not support triggers. What is the best way to work around this problem?

1. Can I skip `CREATE TRIGGER` statements on code generation?
2. Refactor `CREATE TRIGGER` statements into a separate SQL file. Can I skip SQL files based on file name for the code generation?
3. Can I use e.g. docker to start a MariaDB server which is used instead H2 for code generation?

Or maybe you have a better or nicer idea how to deal with trigger creation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ignore certain statements like this:

```
-- [jooq ignore start]
-- Anything between these two tokens is ignored by the jOOQ parser
CREATE TRIGGER ...
-- [jooq ignore stop]
```

Find the docs here: https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.1/manual/code-generation/codegen-ddl/#N90C34